# popcorn time file exists

Tags: software-installation

I try to install popcorntime on ubuntu 18.04
using this

> sudo mkdir /opt/popcorntime

and this what i got

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/popcorntime’: File exists

Any suggestions what to do ?

Thank you

Comment: The directory already exists. You may safely skip that command and move to the next step in whatever tutorial you were following.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar I would write that up as an answer

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks for taking up the effort to form an answer!

Comment: @somlakj If you have a different question please *create a different question* - your last edit invalidates *all* the answers written below and that's not conducive of the Q/A style here.  But simply remove `/opt/popcorntime` with `sudo rm -rf /opt/popcorntime` and then do teh install from scratch.  Empty your trash bin / recycle bin also, because you've got Popcorntime stuff in the trash which is 90% of the stuff you listed in your 'edit' that I've since reverted.

Comment: @ Thomas, sorry about that will do it next time.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should remove any existing installation and re-install Popcorn Time on your system.

Run it as root.

```
rm -rf /opt/popcorntime
wget -O /tmp/Popcorn-Time.tar.gz \
        https://mirror02.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64.tar.xz
mkdir /opt/popcorntime
tar xf /tmp/Popcorn-Time.tar.gz -C /opt/popcorntime
ln -sf /opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time /usr/bin/Popcorn-Time
rm /tmp/Popcorn-Time.tar.gz
```

Then you can access it by running `Popcorn-Time` in the shell.

Comment: @ Mukesh Sai Kumar, when I type

Comment: @ Mukesh Sai Kumar, when I type >  rm -rf /opt/popcorntime    Lost of line are coming up and all of them say  rm cannot remove /opt/popcorntime/........permission Denied

Comment: I directed you to run the commands as root. Please read my complete answer patiently, word-by-word, before doing anything. You are getting "permission denied" because you didn't run my command as root.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to run as root. i just open terminal and type it.

Comment: The root user is like the Administrator in Windows. If you want to install software, make critical system changes etc., you run commands as root. If you want to run commands as root, you must open a root shell. For that, use `sudo su -`.

Comment: Seeing that you are rather new to Linux, I would ask you to read the commands carefully before executing them, as getting a single command wrong would mess up your system entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102507/discussion-between-somlakj-and-mukesh-sai-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

I would use

`file /opt/popcorntime`

to check what is there  (`stat /opt/popcorntime` would work too), it maybe a file (not a directory), and you cannot have a directory and file of the same name (*how would the system know if you mean directory or file*)

As I read the error message, a file of that name already exists.  You need to rename or move the file (*sorry I don't know what it is, so am unsure of the consequences of it*)

Comment: /opt/popcorntime: directory
That I got. as i do all but in not install or something gone wrong with it.How can i remove all this and Try to install it again.

Comment: @Mukesh Sai Kumar was correct then.